# Changing the spacing between textLabel and detailTextLabel in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way one can change the spacing between textLabel and detailTextLabel in a UITableViewCell ? (without subclassing UITableViewCell)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom subclass of [`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and implement the [`-layoutSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW27) method to do this:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];
  //my custom repositioning here
}
```

If you wanted to do it without subclassing, you could do it via method swizzling, but on the whole, that's a Bad Idea™.

Comment: Is it not possible without subclassing?

Comment: @iPhone Developer - Yes it is possible without subclassing, but it involves diving into the runtime and manually switching around methods and stuff.  Totally feasibly and not that difficult, but it makes your implementation much more fragile.  Plus it would affect *every* `UITableViewCell` in your app, as opposed to just a couple here and there.

Comment: @iPhone Developer: If you ever need to change the default UITableViewCell, subclassing is always the best way. @Dave: Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without subclassing using NSAttributedString and the attributedText property like so:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyReuseIdentifier"];

NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some Text"];
cell.textLabel.attributedText = text;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *subtitleParagraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
subtitleParagraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 20;

NSMutableAttributedString *subText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some Subtitle Text"] mutableCopy];
[subText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:subtitleParagraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, subText.length)];

cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = subText;
```

What you're doing is forcing the line height of the subtitle to be larger than normal. Playing around with the line heights of the text and sub text should help you achieve what you want. Should be compatible with iOS 7+.

A few years too late, but hopefully somebody finds it useful.